# Autoloading Class files and instantiating a class - Admin backend

Tags: php, object-oriented, classes

At the moment I am auto loading my classes with:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require_once 'classes/class.'. $class .'.php';
});
```

And instantiating the class with:

```
$backend = new backend();
$dashboard = new dashboard();
$article = new article();
$video = new video();
$theme = new theme();
```

These are in a config file required on every action page of my admin section.

`backend` is my main class holding `database` functions and other global functions.

The other classes all `extends` `backend`.

As I understand it, I could call `backend` functions through for example `article`, as it is an extension of the class.

Is this a good method for instantiating the classes, or is there a way I can call them automatically without having to write these in the config file at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `spl_autoload_register()` is a well known and recommended way of auto-loading classes.

And of course you can't call objects without having them instantiated first.

Comment: The way I'm doing it just looks so unprofessional, is there a cleaner way to instantiate?

Comment: The **only** way to instantiate a class is like `new ClassName();`. "*To create an instance of a class, the new keyword must be used.*" - [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new).